# I cannot install Java. It locks

Tags: apt, java, openjdk

Here is where it locks-up:

Setting up `openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1) ...`

Even `control-c` does not stop it. I have to close the ssh session by closing the terminal.

I have tried two packages: `openjdk-6-jdk` and `ecj` From `Javac`.

What to do now ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a bug: [lists.launchpad.net/openjdk/msg05767.html](http://lists.launchpad.net/openjdk/msg05767.html)

Solution:

apt-get clean

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to install sun's **(sun-java6-jdk** for natty) official version.

I think the quality of openjdk really increased lately, but it's still a copy of the official distribution.

You may also try to install it from the command-line (`sudo apt-get install [package]`). It may give you more feedback on what goes wrong.

Comment: I am in the command line... I will try sun-java6-jdk... Question will it work for Thrift: http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftInstallation and http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftRequirements and http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/GettingUbuntuPackages

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I tried to purge ecj from dpkg, but for some reason it does not work: dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of ecj:
 ecj-gcj depends on ecj (>= 3.5.1-1).
dpkg: error processing ecj (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ecj

Answer (score 0):

As Roalt said, install Sun Java.

1 - Go to [Oracle Java Download](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp?locale=en)

2 - Select **Linux (self-extracting file) filesize: 20.6 MB**

3 - Save the file to **/home/YourUserName/Downloads**

In Terminal, **copy and paste** the following commands

1 - **`cd /opt`**

2 - **`sudo mkdir java`**

Press Enter.

Type your password. You won't see anything, not even dots, this is normal.
Press Enter.

3 - **`cd java`**

4 - **`sudo mkdir 32`**

5 - **`sudo mv ~/Downloads/jre-6u25-linux-i586.bin /opt/java/32`**

Press Enter.

6 - **`sudo chmod 755 /opt/java/32/jre-6u25-linux-i586.bin`**

7 - **`cd /opt/java/32`**

8 - **`sudo ./jre-6u25-linux-i586.bin`**

9 - **`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/java/32/jre1.6.0_25/bin/java" 1`**

Press Enter.

**Note:** are you updating from a previous Java version, which you have removed manually? Then you'll need to execute the above command twice, because you'll get an error message the first time.

10 - **`sudo update-alternatives --set java /opt/java/32/jre1.6.0_25/bin/java`**

11 - **`mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins`**

12 - **`sudo apt-get remove icedtea6-plugin`**

13 - **`rm ~/.mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so`**

14 - **`ln -s /opt/java/32/jre1.6.0_25/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/`**

**Final check**

Now close and restart Firefox or Chrome. Check if everything has succeeded. Type in the url bar of Firefox (not in the terminal!):

**about:plugins**

Press Enter.

And scroll down, until you see something approximately similar to this:
Java(TM) Plug-in 1.6.0_25

All the commands are from [Easy Linux Tips Project](http://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java) and I can confirm that they do work as I have followed these instructions when installing the latest version of Java

Comment: First I cannot find: jre-6u25-linux-i586.bin Second: I am using Ubuntu server. I don't have any browsers installed. I have been trying to install Thrift. But it seems impossible for some reason.

Comment: I have solved it! It seems there was a bug: https://lists.launchpad.net/openjdk/msg05767.html Anyways... Thanks, you all.